# Font-Awesome is not loading Edge & IE

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, netdna-api

I am trying to use [netdna.bootstrapcdn.com](https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css). It's working perfectly in Firefox and Chrome but not loading in IE - 11 or Edge.

Importing the CSS library like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

The error is throwing in browser console is :[image]

Even tried copy/download CSS texts and paste in a custom file and importing the same file then it breaking in all browsers.

Comment: Did you try with HTTPS - `href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"`?

Comment: Try it like this:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />`

Comment: @kiner_shah tried this but not working. Thanks.

Comment: @tolik518 tried this but not working. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Does the console throw any error? Please edit the post and include what you have tried and what errors you get.

Comment: @kiner_shah tried `href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"` and same error in console i.e : `net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Comment: So you get CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. Did you try opening that link directly from browser?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error due to bad URL reference. In the example below, the `href` attribute of the Font-Awesome library has been edited.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<i class="fa fa-adjust" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how you are setting things up - for example when you did the test 'direct' and got the error on all browsers whether you have a doctype, that sort of thing.

However, the basic problem seems to be in the URL syntax. With only // at the start Edge (on my Windows 10 system at least) failed to find the file - after a reasonable pause. Adding the https: Edge was happy and found the file.

This snippet seems to work fine:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```